Co-block-diagonalization of unitary matrices
I have the following open problem.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider two complex squared matrices of the same size verifying $A^n=1$ and $A^{\dagger}=A^{n-1}$.
Can you find an integer k such that the two matrices are, in some basis, block diagonal with blocks of size at most k?
For example, in the case of n=2, one can show it is possible to take k=2.
What can one say for larger n? Any results even for specific n values will be appreciated.

Fundamentally your question is one of the representation theory of the group $G$ generated by your two matrices (call them $A$ and $B$). Some algorithms exist to do computations similar to the ones you are interested in, in the case that the product $AB$ has finite order, too. In this case, the size of the largest block depends on the largest dimensional irreducible factor of $G$ in the representation given by the matrices $A, B$. Thus one cannot say too much in general--it depends on the group in question.
